# Inserting data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in MySQL and I'm trying to enter some values in my database. The database is already made and its based localy.

I have a Schema named 'test' and within the schema I have a table named 'contacts'. Within the contacts I have an id, first and last name.

So I am trying to enter some data in the contacts. This is my php file:

```
<?
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '*******'; // root pass
$db_database    = 'contacts'; 

$link = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);

$query = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('','John','Smith')";

mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

When I run the file on my browser, my database doesnt get any values. **How can I execute that file so that John Smith gets added to my database?**

Comment: @j08691 he can't get any

Comment: I think there is imbalance of fields and values, may be fields are less or more than the values supplied. You may try it http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @j08691 I get no errors or anything. It just my database doesnt get any values

Comment: Have you checked so that your mysql username, password and database are correct? database = the name of the database and not the table (or is your database also named contacts?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your php file has to start with `<?php` instead of `<?`.

Try this:

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost'; 
$db_user        = 'root'; 
$db_pass        = '*******'; // root pass 
$db_database    = 'contacts';  

$link = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass); 
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link); 

$query = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('','John','Smith')"; 

mysql_query($query); 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't... <? is the same as <?php

Comment: @Tom actually that was the problem. I dont know if its my apache problem or anything but once ive set that it worked. Thanks

Comment: Locale <? but itself doesn't work. You can even view the source code it php is missing.

Comment: @JohnyBryne - Ah, yeah. The shorthand version's gotta be supported by the server. Most servers do support it.. apparently yours didnt

Comment: @Antonia - please edit your answer so that I can change my vote

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
mysql_query($query);
```

to

```
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error() . $query);
```

then all will be revealed.

Comment: only in support of unfairly deleted answers.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Please note than I do not have any form or html markup in my php file. Its just the code pasted. So I get no response if the data was added or not.

Answer (score 0):

First how is the structure of your table? If you have only 2 fields on the table that is the error if not please try to post the error the console gives back to you.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contacts (first,last) VALUES ('John', 'Smith')";
$e=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

also do not forget that your table structure says not null for the field id and the default value is null, so it will not accept this kind of insertion

Comment: Dont I have to leave an empty space for the ID? I am a beginner.

Comment: no because you already stated which fields you are going to insert data into!!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider trying PHP ADODB and using AutoExecute with INSERT, if you know your field names

$db->AutoExecute('tablename',array('field1'=>'value','field2'=>'value'));

Can also be used for update:)

http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

Your ID is probably auto_increment, if so add order of attributes to your query :

```
INSERT INTO contacts(`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('John','Smith')
```

Replace `first_name` and `last_name` with your real column names.

Comment: Dont I have to leave an empty space for the ID? I am a beginner.

Comment: no because you already stated which camps you are going to insert